# iOS UITableView AutoSizing Cell with Section Index

Tags: ios, uitableview, indexing, cell, autoresize

I have an app where I load a large plist file in a tableview. This plist file is as a book. It contains chapters and lines. Each row has different length depending on the line length and therefore I need to resize the cell automatically.

I am using storyboard and standard tableview and cell. Cell style=basic and the cell label is set to text=plain lines=0 linebreaks=wordwrap

Up to there, no problem resizing the cell height to the proper size. As the cell height is defined before the text is inserted in the label we have to do it by the well known method of using CGsize and I do it like that (it's working fine)

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:
      (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSString *key = [chapters objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *linesSection = [lines objectForKey:key];
    NSString* theText =  [linesSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    int labelWidth = LW_CHAPTERINDEX_10;
    if (chapters.count < 100){
        if (chapters.count < NB_MIN_CHAP){
            labelWidth = LABELWIDTH;
        } else {
            labelWidth = LW_CHAPTERINDEX_10;
        }
    }

    CGSize textSize = [theText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]
        constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(labelWidth, MAXFLOAT) 
        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return textSize.height;
}
```

The problem is the hardcoding depending on the index. For now I have 3 possibilites.

- No index
- Index with numbers below 10
- Index with numbers below 100

and in the code this part

```
int labelWidth = LW_CHAPTERINDEX_10;
if (chapters.count < 100){
    if (chapters.count < NB_MIN_CHAP){
        labelWidth = LABELWIDTH;
    } else {
        labelWidth = LW_CHAPTERINDEX_10;
    }
}
```

is the hardcoding depending on the 3 possibilities.

I find this was of doing weird, especially if apple will start to deliver more different screen sizes.

**QUESTION**

How can I get the index width at runtime to determine my label width ?

For example i would like to program something like screen.width - index-width to get the label width.

Or any other that should allow it to be dynamical and no more statically hardcoded.

Comment: textSize.width and textSize.heigth+10 is label.frame.size

Comment: And ? I mean this depend on labelWidth I have hardcoded and I want labelWidth to be dynamically determined

Comment: it will be dynamically determined according to your text size to fit in uilabel.

Comment: Prince I am sorry I don't understand what you mean. For me, to determine the texte size I need to use CGSize which ask me to have the width the label. And I don't know this size unless I know the sectionIndex size. Perhaps you could provide me an "answer" showing me the code I shall use. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no (standard) way you can directly access the section index subview. However, you can use the methods for calculating the `CGSize` of text to determine dynamically the width of the section index.

You could determine all possible strings to be returned by `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` beforehand and calculate the necessary size, perhaps padding with some extra pixels left and right. Maybe it is necessary to make some experiments to determine the correct font and size.

Now your approach with something like `screenSize.width - textSize.width - 2*PADDING` should be viable. The only hardcoded thing is now the padding, which should not break things when new screen sizes are introduced.

Comment: Ok so no standard way, that's what I thought. For your idea, that's a good idea that I didn't thought of. I will implement that and try it. Thx for the idea. By the way do you know which system font is used for the sectionindex ?

Comment: I would use `systemFontOfSize` and try out a few. (maybe 8 or so)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to save other people a few hours of work....I laboriously tested various fonts and sizes and margins, comparing them to a UIView hierarchy dump of an actual table view with an index, to arrive at this method which will return the width of a table index, so that the bounds of the table view cell content can be calculated as table_width - index_width.  I will point out that there is often another 20 pixel right-side amount reserved for an accessory view.

I also discovered that the cell.contentView.bounds is NOT correctly set until AFTER cellForRowAtIndexPath and willDisplayCell methods are called, so trying to grab the value during those calls is doomed to fail.  It is set correctly by the time viewDidAppear is called.

I have no idea how to calculate the index width if the device language is set for a non-English alphabet.

```
- (CGFloat) getMaxIndexViewWidth
{
    CGFloat indexMargin = 21.0;   
    NSArray *sectionTitles = [self sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:nil];  //NOTE -- if multiple tables, pass real one in

    CGFloat maxWidth11 = CGFLOAT_MIN;

    for(NSString *title in sectionTitles)
    {
        CGFloat titleWidth11 = [title sizeWithFont:[UIFont  fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:11.0f]].width;
        maxWidth11 = MAX(maxWidth11, titleWidth11);     
    }
    return maxWidth11+indexMargin;
}
```

Comment: I should point out one caveat.  If you have a huge number of indexes (greater than 20 something, not sure the exact number) the table index logic coalesces some of the index titles and only shows a dot to represent them.  If the widest title happens to be one of the hidden ones, then the actual width may be different than the value reported by my code, since it doesn't ignore any titles.